# colors to geom_points variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want make colors to the points in `geom_point` using the `Merge2.m$variable`. How do I do this? Please see my example below (which does not work):

```
ggplot(Merge2.m, aes(x=revDown, y=Term2, color=variable))+ 
  theme_bw(12) +
  geom_point(aes(color=factor(variable)), size=7, colour="black") +
  labs(title="KEGG (Targets for up-regulated miRNAs)", y="KEGG", x="log2 inverted Pvalue")


> head(Merge2.m)
                                    Term variable        value   revDown                                  Term2
1                 Acute myeloid leukemia PValDown 3.490840e-05 14.806066                 Acute myeloid leukemia
2                      Adherens junction PValDown 1.205063e-02  6.374748                      Adherens junction
3 Bacterial invasion of epithelial cells PValDown 2.016157e-05 15.598032 Bacterial invasion of epithelial cells
4            Chemokine signaling pathway PValDown 1.101506e-02  6.504379            Chemokine signaling pathway
5               Chronic myeloid leukemia PValDown 3.964774e-06 17.944330               Chronic myeloid leukemia
6              Circadian rhythm - mammal PValDown 1.672252e-02  5.902064              Circadian rhythm - mammal
```

Comment: why negative reputation on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `colour = "black"`. You can even simply use `geom_point()` without any arguments, since the mapping you want has already been declared.

Here's what you do:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, cyl, color = factor(cyl))) + geom_point(color = "black")
```

Here's what needs to be done:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, cyl, color = factor(cyl))) + geom_point()
```